# OL3 polygon WFS feature search - axis orientation undefined

Tags: openlayers-3, projection, proj

I have an application which allows the user to draw a polygon onto the map, which then uses the JSTS library to do a polygon intersect against a WFS layer and reads features that intersect the user's polygons.

An error occurs once the user has drawn the select polygon onto the map as an error is returned:

'Cannot read property 'getAxisOrientation' of undefined'

This appears to be a projection related issue (I am using the EPSG:27700 projection).

The code for when the user polygon has been drawn is below - would there be a requirement to include the projection in the WFS read features method?

```
draw.on('drawend',function(e){
var extent = e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
var geomA = e.feature.getGeometry();

myDrawSource.clear();
mySelectionsSource.clear();
$.ajax('../../geoserver/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'planning:flood_zone_2',
                srsname: 'EPSG:27700',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:27700'
            }
        }).done(function(resp){
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
        var featuresInExtent = formatWFS.readFeatures(resp);
        var featuresOnDrawPoly = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<featuresInExtent.length;i++){       
        var geomB = featuresInExtent[i].getGeometry();
          if (polyIntersectsPoly(geomA,geomB)===true){
          featuresOnDrawPoly.push(featuresInExtent[i])
          }
        }
        mySelectionsSource.addFeatures(featuresOnDrawPoly);
        //here you may iterate and get the attributes of those falling within the draw polygon
        for (var z=0;z<featuresOnDrawPoly.length;z++){
        console.log("address is ======", featuresOnDrawPoly[z].get('definition'));
        }
        }).fail(function () {
        alert("fail loading layer!!!")
        });

})
```

This is the definition for my proj4 projection, I read about axis and wonder if there is an issue with this definition?

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an alias for `http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700` to `EPSG:27700` as this is the containerSRS read by the GML parser, see: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.addEquivalentProjections

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3898#issuecomment-120899034

Comment: Thank you for the info, it must be this but I am struggling a bit...

I have altered where I set my projection from `var bng = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700');` to `var bng = ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections(
    ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'),
    ol.proj.get('http://epsg.io/27700.gml'));` but I receive an error 'projections.forEach is not a function'.

Do I need to add the alias after I have firstly defined my projection with proj4?

Comment: Sorry that github issue has a typo the function needs to get an array can you try something like: ```var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700',
  axis: 'enu'
});
ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'), proj]);```

Comment: That gets rid of my 'projections.forEach is not a function', but the original error of 'Cannot read property 'getAxisOrientation' of undefined' is still displaying unfortunately. The opengis site has seemed to have changed its URL as well so I am using 'http://epsg.io/27700.gml' which I believe is correct for OGC GML?

Comment: When I debugged I got ```http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700``` as the containerSRS so you need to use that as the code for the equivalent projection. Verify with ol.proj.get('http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700') that it returns the correct projection object.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem now, when loading WFS 1.1.0 features from GeoServer 2.9.1 with OpenLayers 3.17.1.

The srsName especified in the GML was **urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3763** so the following worked for me:

```js
var proj3763 = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:' + 3763,
  extent: [-121656.5849, -294200.8899, 172945.8815, 277430.8421],
  axis: 'enu'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(proj3763);
var proj3763OGC = new ol.proj.Projection({ // srsName from GeoServer GML3 (WFS)
  code: 'urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:' + 3763,
  axis: 'enu',
  extent: [-121656.5849, -294200.8899, 172945.8815, 277430.8421]
});
ol.proj.addProjection(proj3763OGC);
ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([proj3763OGC, proj3763]);
```